# What is the use of Main Interface option in the build settings for iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xib

When I start a single view application and instead of assigning the `rootViewController` programmatically from `AppDelelgate`, try to use the 'Main Interface' option to assign a `xib` as my main interface file, a `SIGABRT` signal is sent to the program when I run it. 
 Why does this happen? What is the purpose of the 'Main Interface' option?

Comment: Can you show more detail about the abort, as reported at the console?

Comment: It doesn't show anything. Just the **SIGABRT** signal is sent to the program message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out how to do this. It was very obvious after I understood the whole process of how the application is loaded. So I thought I'll answer my own question.

The key is to initialize the window and set up the `UIApplication` and its delegate from the xib itself.

- **Step 1**: Create an xib with a `UIWindow` object in it. Make the file's
  owner of the xib as `UIApplication`.
- **Step 2**: Create an `AppDelegate` object in the xib and connect the
  file's owner's `delegate` outlet to this object.
- **Step 3**: Create an outlet for the window in the `AppDelegate` class.
- **Step 4**: Select the **MainInterface** option in build settings as the
  xib you created.
- **Step 5**: Comment out the code in
  `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

If you run the program it will show the window in the simulator, but you'll get a warning that application is supposed to have a `rootViewController` at the end of application launch.

- **Step 6**: So inside `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` we can
  instantiate a `UIViewController` and assign the window outlets
  rootViewController as this view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a .xib file as the Main Interface but I believe it is then assumed that the File's Owner is a UIApplication object.  This is a way of structuring an application that was common with earlier version of Xcode.  If you find projects that contain a MainWindow.xib file, it's likely they use that style.

Comment: I tried running the application after assigning the file's owner as UIApplication. Still I am facing the same problem. After commenting out the auto generated code in applicationDidFinsishLoading: the error doesn't show up ,but in console as expected 'root view controller is required' message is shown.

Comment: Do you have anything connected to the Files Owner that doesn't have a matching property in a UIApplication object?

Comment: No. There isn't anything connected. After creating a new project only changes I have made is fill in the Main Interface option and comment out the code from applicationDidFinishLoading:.

Comment: Now changed the file's owner as UIApplication. Thats it.

Comment: If you're not using a .xib file that was designed to be a Main Interface, your best option is to not do it!  (When I answered your original question, I was assuming the you were using an old-style xib.)

Comment: Well, I am just trying out different things. :) Can you tell me the things to be done to make an xib designed to be a Main Interface?