# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am quite new in XCode and I am trying to build my first (serious non example application). The last days, I have attended a seminar on XCode and I am trying to follow the exact steps we did there in the examples in order to build me own app.

I am facing the following issue: 
When I am trying to run the application I am getting the following error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'**

I am creating an new project and I insert an new .h, .m and xib file (New File --> Obkective-C Class, Class:ASViewController, Subclass UIViewController and I also check the With XIB for user interface)

I leave my xib file empty! No controls inside.

I go to the ASAppDelegate.m and I am making the connection of this with my xib file in order to run the app with this xib file.

```
#import "AS_MainViewController.h" 
#import "ASAppDelegate.h"

@implementation INGAppDelegate

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

AS_MainViewController *MyrootViewController = [[AS_MainViewController alloc]
                        initWithNibName:@"AS_MainViewController" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];

self.window.rootViewController = MyrootViewController;

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

My ASAppDelegate.h is like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ASAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

finally, I go to the Summary of the application and in the section **iPhone / iPod Deployment Info** in the *Main Interface* drop down list I chese the AS_MainViewController

I build and build success, I run it and I am getting this error!

Does anyone have any idea on a possible solution?

Thank you.

Comment: You're nib or xib file is messed up. Is the xib's view set to the file owner?

Comment: The xib file is a new one. I order to avoid this situation, I have created a new project, totally new files. And I have not placed any controls on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is with this step:

> finally, I go to the Summary of the application and in the section
>   iPhone / iPod Deployment Info in the Main Interface drop down list I
>   choose the AS_MainViewController

Don't do this. Then it will work.

If you want to run application by choosing an xib in the *Main Interface* section then I have given an answer over here:
[What is the use of Main Interface option in the build settings for iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375712/what-is-the-use-of-main-interface-option-in-the-build-settings-for-ios-applicati)
Check it out.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like this solved the issue. I am continuing and I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Open your Xib file,  right click on File's Owner. Remove all the yellow warning flags and then re-run it

Comment: I did it. Right click on the File's Owner. There are no warning flags.